# Swift = operator does not return anything, So how does optional binding works?

Tags: swift

As per docs, Swift `"="` operator does not return anything so that it cannot be used in place of `"=="`. So how does optional binding works?

Like

```
    if let a = optionalStringFoo {
      //do some thing
    } else {
      //do something
    }
```

Comment: Please read the section *Optional Binding* in [Swift Language Guide: The Basics - Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330)

Comment: `optionalStringFoo` will be assigned to `a` and if blocks will run same like `if a != nil`.

Comment: @vadian The more direct link is https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID333

Comment: @vadian Thanks for pointing me to docs but I have been there what confuses me is if = does not return anything (as per docs) how will " let a = someOptional" will return true or false?

Comment: @amar Don't think of this as a normal `if` with a boolean expression. Think of it as the `if let` statement, not the `if` statement.

Comment: @amar The true or false statement lays within wether it is nil or not

Comment: @amar Did you ever run `if obj { }` or `if !obj { }` line `Objective-C` ? This checks for if the `obj` is `nil` or `not nil`. In `Swift` `if let a = optionalStringFoo { }` this will check if `a != nil`. This is just to avoid the `!` else you can write `if a != nil { print(a!)}`

Comment: @rmaddy sounds logical +1

Comment: @TheTiger the code you have written has the same effect but does not explain the optional binding behavior Martin R explained it.

Comment: @amar Absolutely!! because He is genius and I'm a common man ;)

Comment: @TheTiger we all are learning different stages though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let a = optionalStringFoo` does not return a (boolean) value, note that

```
if (let a = optionalStringFoo) { ... }
```

does *not* compile.

Optional binding is a special case of the if-statement built into the Swift grammar. [Statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html) in the Swift Language Reference shows the following productions:

> if-statement → **if** condition-list code-block else-clause<sub>opt</sub>
>
> condition-list → condition | condition , condition-list
>
> condition → expression | availability-condition | case-condition | optional-binding-condition
>
> optional-binding-condition → **let** pattern initializer | **var** pattern initializer
>
> pattern → identifier-pattern type-annotation<sub>opt</sub>
>
> identifier-pattern → identifier
>
> initializer → **=** expression

Therefore, in

```
if let a = optionalStringFoo { ... }
```

the `if` keyword is followed by an "optional-binding-condition" where `a` is the "identifier-pattern" and `= optionalStringFoo` is the "initializer".